# Difference between the total steps and the sum of all the steps in the source screen

Tags: google-fit

On the source data screen from the link　"See source data", there are the total steps and the list of all step entries like this screenshot.

[image: Source screen]

We found that sometimes the total steps and the sum of the steps of all the entries, which we manually calculate, are different.

Here are my questions.

1. Could you let me know what causes this difference?
2. The entries shown on this screen are also different from the entries in the download data from Google (takeout data). Could you let me know why?

The sum of the steps in the download data is the same as the total steps in the source screen of Google Fit.

Thank you.

Comment: Just found this in the doc that could help you out.

"The Google Fit app shows this more accurate, estimated step count on both the Android and iOS app, and the Google Fit app on smart watches with Wear OS.

If you read by your app's data source rather than by data type, and your app only uses local step data, the step count will be different from the step count in the Google Fit app.

If you're reading the data types but values are still different from the Google Fit app, this temporary difference in numbers could be due to syncing delays"

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Are these assumptions correct?
1. There are 2 ways to get the number of steps. One is the data source, and another is the data type.
2. The number of the data type is more "accurate".
3. The total steps shown in the source screen of Google Fit comes from the data type, and each step entry in the same screen comes from the data source.